# Shorter regex for days of week/months range

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match the days of week in two formats: the normal way, like "mon", "fri", etc, but I also need in the same regex for a range type of format, like "mon-fri"

Same for months:
"jan", "feb"
"jan-dec"

I have this working regex:

`^((jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)|((jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)-(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)))$`

But it's huge and not sure if ideal.

Comment: This sounds like it might not be best done with a regex.  What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: @AndyLester I'm using it in the Joi validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)(-(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec))?$
```

Comment: is that small??

Comment: @Shubh It's *shorter* as OP wants

Comment: That's actually better, so thank you! Yes I wanted a shorter one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you unfortunately didn't list your language, so I assume anything goes.

```
(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)(?:-(?1))?
```

List your months in a capturing group, then recurse the same subpattern using `(?1)`, and make it optional along with the dash `(?:-...)?`

[See it here](https://regex101.com/r/KQQ2uV/1)

Comment: He wanted his current code shorter. Didn’t say anything about optimizations. A word boundary `\b` would be a simple fix though.

Comment: Ah I just noticed he had anchors though so that was on me :)

Comment: Fair enough, didn't pay attention to that. Another possibility that would prevent possible compatibility issues with recursive patterns would simply be to enclose all the months in a non-capturing group ending with an optional `-` and allow 1 or 2 matches `(?:(jan|…|dec)-?){1,2}`.